# How to set the NumberFormat in FlatFileItemReaderBuilder with Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm creating a Spring Batch reading a csv file. I've decimal values in the files that are expressed in the European format (with comma).

My readed is:

```
@Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<OphthalmicLens> hoyaReader() {
        //@formatter:off
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<OphthalmicLens>().name("ItemReader")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\\\sviluppo\\\\optix\\\\lenses\\\\hoya\\\\lenses.csv"))).
                delimited().delimiter(";")
                .names(new String[] { "BARCODE","LENTE","TRATTAMENTO","COLORE","SFERO","CILINDRO","RL","ADDIZIONE","DIAMETRO"})
                .linesToSkip(1)
                .lineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<>())
                .fieldSetMapper(new HoyaOphthalmicLensMapper())
                .build();
        //@formatter:on
    }
```

I got that a `DefaultFieldSet` is used and reading the javadoc:

```
/**
     * The {@link NumberFormat} to use for parsing numbers. If unset the US
     * locale will be used ('.' as decimal place).
     * @param numberFormat the {@link NumberFormat} to use for number parsing
     */
    public final void setNumberFormat(NumberFormat numberFormat) {
        this.numberFormat = numberFormat;
        if (numberFormat instanceof DecimalFormat) {
            grouping = "" + ((DecimalFormat) numberFormat).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();
            decimal = "" + ((DecimalFormat) numberFormat).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator();
        }
    }
```

The US locale is used by default. I don't see how to customize the number format from my reader.
Do you have some hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DefaultFieldSetFactory` is what creates `DefaultFieldSet` instances. You can set the number format with your locale on this factory and pass it to the `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder`. For example:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<OphthalmicLens> hoyaReader() {

   Locale locale = Locale.getDefault(); // set your locale
   DefaultFieldSetFactory fieldSetFactory = new DefaultFieldSetFactory();
   fieldSetFactory.setNumberFormat(NumberFormat.getInstance(locale));

   return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<OphthalmicLens>().name("ItemReader")
        .resource(new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\\\sviluppo\\\\optix\\\\lenses\\\\hoya\\\\lenses.csv")))
        .delimited()
        .delimiter(";")
        .fieldSetFactory(fieldSetFactory)
        .names(new String[] { "BARCODE","LENTE","TRATTAMENTO","COLORE","SFERO","CILINDRO","RL","ADDIZIONE","DIAMETRO"})
        .linesToSkip(1)
        .lineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<>())
        .fieldSetMapper(new HoyaOphthalmicLensMapper())
        .build();
    }
}
```